# A centralized way to manage static text portlets?

Tags: plone

Does there exist Plone add-on, or method, for centralized portlet text management?

A site has a set of standard static text portlets which text is updated time to time. The assigment of portlets do not follow any particular rules. For example, the same static text may appear in two different folders.

Could it be possible to centralize the management of this text, so that you can change it in one place and it would be automatically updated across different portlet assignments?

Could reference portlet + rendering hack do this?

Plone 4.1b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking at [collective.portlet.content](http://plone.org/products/collective.portlet.content)

You can create content in a reserved, administrative section of your site and have it referenced and rendered site-wide as a portlet. I'm using it in combination with Products.ContentWellPortlets to render header and footer text.